# MS Access Query Logic

Tags: ms-access

I know nothing about MS Access but am trying to help a colleague. They have a database with job titles and he wants to find anyone who is a CEO but not anyone that is an "Assistant to the CEO." Some titles are "CEO", "CEO & Founder", "CEO & CTO", etc. Some of the titles he doesn't want are "Assistant to the CEO", "Administrative Assistant to the CEO", etc. I think the query

```
(Like "*CEO*") AND (Like "assis*")
```

should return titles that are not the former titles I mentioned, but Access returns nothing.

Comment: `WHERE EmployeeName <> 'Gareth Keenan' Or EmployeeName <> 'Dwight Shrute'` perhaps?

Comment: Seriously though, the code you provided would look for job titles that *start* with `assis` and also then have `CEO` somewhere in them. Do you have any like that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On a dataset like this:

[image]

The following query...

```sql
SELECT tblJobTitle.[JobTitle]
FROM tblJobTitle
WHERE tblJobTitle.[JobTitle] Like "*CEO*" And tblJobTitle.[JobTitle] Not Like "*to the CEO*"
```

..returns:

[image]

...you may want to define more strings to exclude (`JobTitle Not Like`...) depending on what your data is looking like.